# When user "A" comments on the blog of user "B", should we notify a message into a "SENT Message Box" of user "A"?

Tags: user-behavior

I am building an app that allows users to comment blog of other user. Each user will have their own message box. Let see this example:

```
User "A" sent a message "your blog is great" to a blog "Life is great" (title of blog) of user "B".
```

Ok, so every developer will decide to notify the "INBOX message box" of user "B" like this:

```
In the INBOX of user "B":
User "A" commented on your blog "Life is great" (time: 2014-11-12)
```

But what about user "A"?

-should we notify a message into a "SENT Message Box" of user "A" as well?

-is it necessary?

-is it improve the user experience of user "A"? or it is unnecessary?

-does user "A" need this kind of info?

Something like this:

```
In the SENT of user "A":
You commented on the blog "Life is great" of user "B" (time: 2014-11-12)
```

Comment: What is the objective of this messaging system

Comment: Just a Private Message Box that allow users to know if someone comment on their blogs. I don't like to use email of user cos it may annoy user, i prefer the private Buit-in message box right on my webapp

Comment: I'm curious, only registered user can comment? with most blogs, anyone can comment as long as they provide name and email, how would you notify those people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add this concept of the Sent messages box, it should definitely not give any sort of alerts/notifications, if that is what you are referring to.  When User A completes an action, they do not need to be notified of their action.

However, there is some merit in tracking past activity like this.  If User A is trying to find a post that they liked and they remembered that they left a comment, going through their sent messages could help them find it quicker.  An activity log would fulfill the same purpose.  In order to implement a records sent messages successfully, it needs to achieve the following things:

- The user should be able to click on a sent message to redirect to the actual comment on the page.
- The user should receive notifications of any replies to their comments.
- The most useful reason to have the sent messages in the box is if they could be linked to notifications of replies to that comment, like an email chain.  When a user receives notice that another user has replied to their comment, being able to easily access their comment will give them the context of the reply.  Without this feature, there is no reason to store the "sent messages" as messages.  Rather, they could just be included in an activity log.